# Why isn't the KafkaTransactionManager being applied to this Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Producer?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have configured a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka application to use transactions ([full source code available on Github](https://github.com/codependent/kafka-outbox-pattern.git)):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: message-relay-service
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: message-relay-tx-
            producer:
              configuration:
                retries: 1
                acks: all
                key:
                  serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

      bindings:
        output:
          destination: transfer
          contentType: application/*+avro
      schema-registry-client:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      schema:
        avro:
          subjectNamingStrategy: org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.QualifiedSubjectNamingStrategy
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9090/mem:mydb
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

server:
  port: 8085
```

This app has a scheduled task that periodically checks records to send in a database using a `@Scheduled` task. This methods is annotated with `@Transactional` and the main class defines `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

However when debugging the code I've realized that the KafkaTransactionManager isn't being executed, that is to say, there are no Kafka transactions in place. What's the problem?

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableBinding(Source::class)
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
class MessageRelayServiceApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MessageRelayServiceApplication>(*args)
}

---

@Component
class MessageRelay(private val outboxService: OutboxService,
                   private val source: Source) {

    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    fun checkOutbox() {
        val pending = outboxService.getPending()
        pending.forEach {
            val message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(it.payload)
                    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, it.messageKey)
                    .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, it.contentType)
                    .build()
            source.output().send(message)
            outboxService.markAsProcessed(it.id)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `@EnableTransactionManagement` in `account-service`, only in `message-relay-service`.

In any case, your scenario is not currently supported; the transactional binder was designed for processors where the consumer starts the transaction, any records sent on the consumer thread participate in that transaction, the consumer sends the offset to the transaction and then commits the transaction.

It was not designed for producer-only bindings; please open a GitHub issue against the binder because it should be supported.

I am not sure why you are not seeing a transaction starting but, even if it does, the problem is that `@Transactional` will use Boot's auto-configured KTM (and producer factory) and the binding uses a different producer factory (the one from your configuration).

Even if a transaction is in process, the producer won't participate in it.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your answer. Actually there's a transaction, but only applies to the DataSource, I don't see the KafkaTransactionManager in the stack as I do when running the transaction-spring-data-processor app from the spring cloud stream samples. However, according to what you said it's normal since it's not supported at the moment. I'll open an issue. Regards!

Comment: You need to use a `ChainedTransactionManager` to synchronize the transactions from a DSTM and KTM. But, as I said, since the producer factories are different, it won't work.

Comment: Link for the issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/689

Comment: The ChainedTransactionManager has been deprecated. What's the recommended approach to perform DB update + kafka message in a single transaction using Spring Cloud Stream (functional programming style) for a producer only transaction?

Comment: The CKTM (actually, its super class) was deprecated because some users had unreasonable expectations of its capabilities; my understanding is that it is deprecated but won't be removed. A "single" transaction is not possible; all you can do is get the commits as close as possible to each other; you have to deal with one succeeding and one failing. You can still use it, or call nested `@Transactional` methods configured with each TM, with the inner method being the one you want to commit first. Call the inner method at the end of the outer and the functionality will be very similar to the CKTM.